# Cannot Render Google+ SignInButton

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I am attempting to follow the Setting Up [Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) tutorial for Android Studio 0.8.6. Ultimately, I want to [add the Google+ sign-in button to my app](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in) (see below for example). When I add the button to my XML, the preview pane (as well as the app itself when I deploy it in debug mode) gives the following error message:

> Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton (Open Class, Show Exception)  Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip
>   code or show sample data when shown in the IDE
>
> Exception Details
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.dynamic.f
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(ClassLoader.java:-2)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:471)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)   at
>   com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.z  at
>   com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.setStyle  at
>   com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.  at
>   com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:778)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:500)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:381) Copy
>   stack to clipboard

I have seen and have attempted to follow steps found in similar questions (most of which are related to Eclipse). I have also attempted to:

- Clean the build.
- Resync Gradle
- Invalidate Caches / Restart
- Re-get the libraries.

Another point of note is that it seems all other Google Play service calls compile. For example, I am make a call to `GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable` with no apparent issues.

Can anybody steer me in the correct direction?

Using the Google+ sign-in button:

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: In Android Studio, "Clear Cache" on preview screen worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in the latest Google Play Services (5.0) code and/or integration with gradle and Android Studio.

I had the same problem and I was able to get around it by downgrading the version of Google Play Services used in my project. I added the following in the `build.gradle` under the dependencies section:

```
dependencies{
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.52'
    ...
}
```

After that, the error went away and the layout designer was able to render the Google+ Sign-In button on the screen.

Comment: That seems to be it. Do you know where I can report this bug?

Comment: but, i am just wondering, dont those google guy test their stuff bfr releasing it??? and if i wanted to work on the v5? no other possible ways besides downgrading how??

Comment: The code will still work if you compiled it with v5. I think the issue here is the integration between the new google play services and the development tools (Android Studio in my case which has problems rendering the button in preview mode). If you just edit the layout in text mode, you can still build the app with v5.

Comment: After using the 4.4.52 --> Sync --> build --> Reopen Android studio

Answer (score 2):

You should add this line to your app's build.gralde:

    `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'`

The latest version is [9.0.2](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup), 4.4.52 is some too older.

In summary, [Integrating Google Sign-In into Your Android App](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in#add-config) has a bug. You must add the above line to your build.gradle file.

Comment: You do realize this question is two years old, right?

Comment: No, just today when I integrate Google sign in module. I find the problem remains, and 4.4.52 is indeed so lower. I believe my answer make sense.

Comment: Nobody's using Android Studio 0.8.6 or GMS 4.4.52 nowadays. Please stop trying to rack up points on obsolete questions and focus on meaningful posts and actually helping others. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I got it. In my answer, I post the problem's cause link, and gms version link, hope to help other side. Anyway, Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for this. swbandit's answer from 2014 is now extremely out of date. 4.4.52 is unsafe to use in pretty much every way by now, so this is the more current answer.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the depencency:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.52'
    ...
}
```

you need to rebuild the project.

In Android Studio:

```
Build -> Rebuild Project
```